# Do C# classes default to instance or static classes if not specified?

Tags: c#, oop

When declaring a class in C# without specifying if the class is a static or non-static class which will it default to?

EDIT: Here's an article I wrote based on this discussion.

https://hackernoon.com/c-static-vs-instance-classes-and-methods-50fe8987b231

Comment: You need to create a new instance of it unless you will use the `static` keyword.

Comment: There is no way to specify that a class is an "instance class".

Comment: This should take less than a minute to test.  Is your `exampleClass` static?

Comment: I'm not testing it, just trying to understand the theoretical concept.

Comment: @MBaka Why does trying to understand it prevent you from testing it?  Testing things is a *great* way to understand them.

Comment: Testing it would also have shown you that your code isn't valid.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I've written an article based on this conversation. If you have any feedback I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't declare the class as static then its members can be either static or non-static. 
A static class can only have static members.
You can invoke non-static members only on instances of the class.
You can invoke static members only on the class itself.

Also, in your class declaration, there are no parentheses.

Comment: Removed class declaration

Comment: Excellent response. Super helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If the "static" is not specified, it will require an instance of the class to be used (Unless the member itself is specified as static).

> If the class is not declared as static, client code can use it by creating objects or instances which are assigned to a variable.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes

Comment: Not quite true, you don't *need* to create an instance of it. A non-static class can still contain only static member for example.

Comment: Excellent response.

Answer (score 2):

A class is always an instance class unless you specify otherwise